# Pipe outputstream of one running program to inputstream of other running program

Tags: python, c, shell, unix

I have two programs which are running parallelly. 
I want to redirect the output stream on one program to the input stream of other program. 
I tried piping, but it seems the output of first program is redirected to the input of second program *only on the termination of first program*. 
But, my requirement is not so. 
For example first program is print.c and is as follows:

```
int main(){
        int t=1;
        while(t!=0){
                printf("%d",t);
                scanf("%d",&t);
        }   
}
```

Second program is inputP.py and is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python     
t=1     
while t!=0:    
        f = open('outP.txt','a')    
        t = int(raw_input())    
        f.write(str(t))        
        f.close()
```

My requirement is second program should read the output from first program as soon as it prints a number and none of the two programs terminate.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because UNIX buffers stdin when it detects that it's a pipe. What really happens is that the output of the first program is stored in a buffer until it reaches a certain size or until the program terminates (whichever happens first -- it's a pretty large buffer so you hit the second condition first), and once the buffer is deemed full, it's sent as input to the second program.

So it looks like you want your second (Python) program's input to only be line-buffered (as would happen if you were running the program interactively, with its stdin a tty instead of a pipe).

The module you're looking for is called pexpect: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ .

Answer (score 0):

Your C program, Python program should be modified.

The original C program does print `1` before getting an input. And it does not print the last input value (`0`). Following is modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t = 1;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &t);
        printf("%d\n", t); /* print newline */
        fflush(stdout); /* force flush */
    } while (t != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Python program:

```
t = 1
f = open('outP.txt','a') # Open file once!
while t != 0:
    t = int(raw_input())
    f.write(str(t) + '\n') # print newline
    f.flush()
f.close()
```

---

**UPDATE**

Use [`fflush(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) to force a write of buffer.

See http://asciinema.org/a/6586

Comment: in this solution it seems python program is not reading the output from c program parallelly. Once the c program is done, then python program reads the output from c program and processes it. But my requirement is not so.

Comment: @svKris, I updated the code to use `fflush` and `file.flush`. Check it out.